# A real valued function defined on a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with a countable number of discontinuities is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, measurable-functions, borel-sets

I have proved the following statement and I would like to know if my proof is correct and/or/if/how it can be improved, thanks.

"Suppose $X$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $\{x\in X: f\text{ is not continuous at }x\}$ is a countable set. Prove $f$ is a Borel measurable function."

My proof:

(**EDIT: my proof is wrong in the case** $\{x\in X: f\text{ is not continuous at }x\}$ **is a countable set (a counterexample, as pointed out by Ramiro is the Thomae function) but it should work in the case** $\{x\in X: f\text{ is not continuous at }x\}$ **is finite**)

Let $d_i, i\geq 1$ denote the points at which $f$ is discontinuous and fix $a\in\mathbb{R}$; if $x\in X$ and $f(x)>a$ then either $x=d_i$ for some $i\geq 1$ or $f$ is continuous at $x$ so if we set $\delta_x:=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\inf\{|x-d_i|:i\geq 1\}$ we have $f((x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\cap X)\subseteq (a,+\infty)$ (equivalently $(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\cap X\subseteq f^{-1}((a,+\infty))$ being $f$ continuous in this whole set so $f^{-1}((a,+\infty))=\bigcup_{x\in f^{1}((a,+\infty)), x\neq d_i\forall i\geq 1} (x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\cap X\cup \{d_i:f(d_i)>a\}$ which being the union of two Borel sets ($(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so it is Borel, $X$ is a Borel set by hypothesis so their intersection is Borel too and so is also their union and $\{d_i:f(d_i)>a\}$ is countable hence Borel too) is Borel. So, by LEMMA, we can conclude that $f$ is Borel-measurable, as desired.

---

LEMMA. Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $f^{-1}((a,+\infty))\in\mathcal{S}$ for all $\in\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.

DEF. (measurable function) Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space. A function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is called $\mathcal{S}$-measurable if $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{S}$ for every Borel set $B\subset\mathbb{R}$.

DEF. (Borel-measurable function) Suppose $X\subset\mathbb{R}$. A function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is called Borel measurable if $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set for every Borel set $B\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, your proof is not correct. The issue is that $\delta_x$ may be $0$. In fact, there is a function that is discontinuous on all the rational numbers and continuous on all irrational number (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)).

However, the some ideas in your proof are fine. Here is how they are developed into a correct proof:

Suppose $X$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $\{x\in X: f\text{ is not continuous at }x\}$ is a countable set.

Let $D= \{x\in X: f\text{ is not continuous at }x\}$. Since $D$ is countable, we have that $D$ is a Borel subset. So $E=X\setminus D$ is a Borel subset and $f|_E: E \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, so $f|_E$ is a Borel measurable function.

It means that, for all $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $B$ is Borel measurable, then $f|_E^{-1}(B)$ is Borel measurable. Now, since $X=E \cup D$, we have
$$f^{-1}(B) = (f^{-1}(B) \cap E) \cup (f^{-1}(B)\cap D)= f|_E^{-1}(B) \cup (f^{-1}(B)\cap D)$$
We know that $f|_E^{-1}(B)$ is Borel measurable and that $f^{-1}(B)\cap D$ is countable (and so Borel measurable). It follows that  $f^{-1}(B)$ is Borel measurable.

So, we have proved that,  for all $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $B$ is Borel measurable, $f^{-1}(B)$ is Borel measurable.  It means that $f$ is a Borel measurable function.

Comment: great answer, very instructive, thank you.